# Strange apostrophe issue in web form > SQL Server

Tags: sql

We look after a site for a client on which they have a page with a HTML form text area that gets written to a SQL Server ntext field.

One of their customers was updatng their profile using this form and mentioned that when they entered the word  "don't" into the form and then viewed their profile the word had changed to:

dÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢t

I've done some searches for this on Google, and surprisingly there's over 2 million pages on sites where this seems to of happened - but I can't see any information about it.

Interestingly, If I write into the form I don't get the same issue and was wondering if it was a result of a 'strange' apostrophe from some pasted text into the form?

Anyone else came across this?

Comment: This looks like a Unicode issue. `nvarchar` accepts multi-byte characters. Check the customer's end-user's language/regional settings. They're probably using a different code page than your client's web site or database is expecting or designed to handle.

Comment: `ƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢` looks like a classic result of iso-8859-1-vs-utf-8. The strange apostrophe may have forced the browser into submitting as utf-8, exposing the underlying problem. Can you repro if you put non-iso-8859-1 text in the form?

Comment: I pasted 军售反映对华政策冒险性 in and it is displayed fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the HTML page where the form is located doesn't have a [meta charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html) tag defined, leaving the option of which character set to use up to the browser's preferences/defaults.